# How to read string including escape characters in C using popen() in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, escaping, popen

I have to display all the files and sub-directories in a directory in Linux (more specifically, Ubuntu 19.10) using popen() in C. The relevant code is given below. The problem when I debug this code is, that, the "list" variable contains only up to the first "\n" escape character, which is ".:\n". How can I detour so that popen() outputs all the string including escape sequence characters?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *read_file;
    char list[1000];

    read_file = popen("ls -R","r");
    fgets(list, 1000, read_file);
    pclose(read_file);

    printf("%s", list);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Use `fgets` in a loop until it returns `NULL`?

Comment: Er, why not do it all it all in C with `opendir()`/`readdir()`/`lstat()`/etc.? (There's also `scandir()`, but it's not recursive AFAIK).